# ODOO 14 - CRM - Set the name of company to the title of opportunity

Tags: odoo, field, crm

Today, I try to **define the title of my opportunities** in the CRM **as the name of the selected company**.

Voici mon code :

```py
class crm_lead(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'crm.lead'

    @api.onchange('partner_id')
    def _onchange_amount1(self):
        if self.partner_id:
            self.name = self.partner_id
```

**But here is the result :**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2zje.png

Can someone tell me how can i do to display the name of the field please ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you show your XML of that view?

Comment: i don't have any XML because i just wanna set the default value of the 'name' fields when i create the opportunity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
class crm_lead(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'crm.lead'

    @api.onchange('partner_id')
    def _onchange_amount1(self):
        if self.partner_id:
            self.name = self.partner_id.name
```

The "name" field, I supossed is a Char, so it needs to get a string value.

Comment: ahahah i tried with "self.partner_id.name()" but not "self.partner_id.name" i'm stupid, thank you !

Comment: it happens to everyone :)